# Where are the bears for Bear Minimum?

Tags: borderlands-2

I combed almost every inch of Wildlife Exploitation Preserve and cleared every last pile of stalker goo I found and didn't see a single teddy bear. Where's the "stalker goo" that has the bears for this challenge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it turns out they aren't in the "breakable" goo piles but actually suspended in the solid "drips" of stalker goo. You have to "collect" them with Pick Up/Action for them to count. This video has the locations:

Note this is another challenge you may as well do solo, only one person can grab any individual bear and they don't count for everyone.

Comment: Playing split screen, I picked up 2 of the bears and they counted for my girlfriend who was playing too o: food for thought

Comment: @Eight8itnarwhal that's the same for every quest in co-op. Quests and objectives are shared.

Comment: @Alex quests are, challenges generally aren't though. This could be an exception, but I know for example Cult of the Vault and Jimmy Jenkins quests don't count for more than one player

Comment: @BenBrocka oh is this a badass challenge? Didn't know that..